# three.js rotate camera in plane

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, three.js, perspectivecamera

I have a camera in my app:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 1;
camera.position.y = -5;
camera.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), degInRad(90));
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
```

Those code in `render` function must rotate the camera while I'm pressing the keys:

```
if (leftPressed) {
    camera.rotateOnAxis((new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)).normalize(), degInRad(1));
} else if (rightPressed) {
    camera.rotateOnAxis((new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)).normalize(), degInRad(-1));
}
if (upPressed) {
    camera.rotateOnAxis((new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)).normalize(), degInRad(1));
} else if (downPressed) {
    camera.rotateOnAxis((new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)).normalize(), degInRad(-1));
}
```

Camera rotates, but not in way I need. I want that camera rotates like in FPS (first person shooter) on plane. See picture to understand what I want...
I'm try to use `sin(1)` and `cos(1)` but can't understand how `rotateOnAxis` works, cause `translate` functions work like a charm and moves camera in direction in what she sees.
**P.S.**
Here is a [docs](http://threejs.org/docs/) to the `three.js` maybe it helps.
To handle keyboard events I use [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/)
And here is a `degInRad` function:

```
function degInRad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Link on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/)

[image: camera rotation]

`O` - position of camera
`O-O1` - current camera direction
`R1` - current rotation direction
`R` - direction what I want
Sorry for *good* picture.

Comment: Consider, instead, using/modifying, `THREE.PointerLockControls`. See http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html. Note in the pointer-lock source code how the camera is added as a child/grandchild of 2 objects to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: @WestLangley, it's nice link, thanks, but I don't need to move camera with mouse. And `camera` uses only in `controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera ); scene.add( controls.getObject() );` - it's `PointerLockControls` inner object adds to scene, not `camera` itself and in `onWindowResize` function - just applying new properties, and in `renderer.render( scene, camera );` - here is using original `camera` variable. About what `child/grandchild` You talk? I really can't understand, can You explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice how `PointerLockControls` rotates the camera as you desire, except it uses the mouse, instead of the keyboard. To get that effect, it uses the `pitchObject` and `yawObject` technique. See the source code. That is what I meant by `child/grandchild`. You do not have to use the `PointerLockControls`; you can implement similar logic yourself.

Comment: @WestLangley it's my fail. I don't see source code of [PointerLockControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js) on page. Now I give a try and if all be fine I give an answer to a question or ask You if I make an error.

Comment: @WestLangley I wrote work example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/2/). But I can't understand why developers of three.js use those `pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) );` construction in code. When I uncomment this lines in my code vertical moving works bad. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: You have a bug. `Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, cameraHolder.rotation.x ) )`

Comment: Just a slip. You can compare of performance in [3](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/3/) and [4](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/4/) versions. Third version with commented strings have a better vertical moving. Question is why are they use those construction?

Comment: Your code has errors. I can answer questions about three.js, but I can't help you debug your code. Sorry. I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks again. There is a hard to debug three.js app on jsfiddle I have a lot of errors while copy/patse my code. This string `pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) )` allow see in *sky* or on *floor* and don't go on next circle - here is a answer on my question in comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might get what you want simply by setting `camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';`

Comment: +1.  Yes, and simply increment/decrement `camera.rotation.x`and `.y` directly.

Comment: I think it's a better solution, thanks. Now I see that `Object3D.rotation` is a `Euler` not `Vector3` type...

Answer (score 5):

believe what your looking for conceptually is a camera rig setup. In this approach you first build an `Object3D` to be the "neck", then attach the camera to that object with your desired rotation. Then you can apply the rotations to the `Object3D` to look around without the wobble effect. To carry it further you could nest that "neck" object in another `Object3D` to act as the "body" and apply the translations to that object to move about the scene. In this way you have a basic camera controller rig. I modified your fiddle like so:

Edit: implementation change to better suit @ostapische use case. Here's the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/2/)

```
function degInRad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}
/////////////////////////////////
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    if (leftPressed) {
        neck.rotation.y += degInRad(1);
    } else if (rightPressed) {
        neck.rotation.y -= degInRad(1);
    }
    if (upPressed) {
        camera.rotation.x += degInRad(1);
    } else if (downPressed) {
        camera.rotation.x -= degInRad(1);
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
/////////////////////////////////
var scene, camera, renderer, grass, neck;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
/////////////////////////////////
window.onload = function() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    cameraHolder = new THREE.Object3D();
    cameraHolder.add( camera );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.rendererSize = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight, quality: 100, maxQuality: 400, minQuality: 20};
    renderer.setSize( renderer.rendererSize.width, renderer.rendererSize.height );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var texture, material, geometry, element;

    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(24, 24);   
    grass = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    grass.name = "grass";
    scene.add( grass );

    neck = new THREE.Object3D();
    neck.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), degInRad(90));
    neck.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    neck.position.z = 1;
    neck.position.y = -5;


    neck.add(camera);
    scene.add(neck);    

    KeyboardJS.on('left', function() { leftPressed = true; }, function() { leftPressed = false; });
    KeyboardJS.on('right', function() { rightPressed = true; }, function() { rightPressed = false; });
    KeyboardJS.on('up', function() { upPressed = true; }, function() { upPressed = false; });
    KeyboardJS.on('down', function() { downPressed = true; }, function() { downPressed = false; });

    render();
}
```

I was going to mention the PointLockControl or FirstPersonControl, but I see WestLangley has been so kind to suggest. Anyway good luck,

Comment: You have an errors in your code, but @WestLangley give me a good idea to see source code of PointerLockControls. Can you add [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uFwFC/2/) link to your answer or modify your code to work state and can I approve answer.

Comment: There we go, the modified code has been updated. Thanks for the consideration, and thanks to @WestLangley for the solid advice.